# Placing grid tables in R

Tags: r, datagrid, plot, weibull

I want to use grid.table() in an existing plot in R. However I can't locate this table on the right side of my chart. So the thing is:

First of all, I make an histogram of my data:

```
hist(as.numeric(unlist((vels[counts]))),freq=F,
  col="gray",border="black",ylim=c(0,0.15),
  xlab=paste(names(vels)[counts]),
  main=paste("Weibull fitting",names(vels[counts])))
```

After that, I have implemented a function that plots in an existing chart the Weibull curve giving both parameters A and K:

```
plot_weibull(K_value,A_value)
```

And finally I want to place a data.frame using the grid.table() because it shows the cells in a very pretty form, and you can use italic and bold text in cells.

```
grid.table(round(values,3),cex=0.75,show.rownames=T,
  show.colnames=T,show.hlines=T)
```

The problem is that this table appears in the center of the device in front of the histogram and the curve, and I want it to be in the right side.

After all, I would like to know a tool that clicking on the graph, I would receive the area under my Weibull curve.

Comment: What do you mean by a grid-table?  You should also provide some code as to what you're already done that gives a reproducible example if possible.

Comment: There is a `locator()` function for base graphics and a `grid.locator()` function for grid graphics. Seems unlikely that you are using a function named `grid-table`, since dashes are invalid in function names. It's also unclear what you mean by "weibull plot". Include the package names and code to create an example if you want tested responses.

Comment: Excuse me for not being clear enough. 
I make an histrogram of wind speeds, and after I have implemented a function that fits weibull curve to the histogram.
Once I have represented the histogram and the weibull curve, I want to plot in the same graph a dataframe using the function grid.table() because it is very nice and can put the values of dataframe in italic or bold forms. This dataframe is a table of two columns, and the function represents it in the middle of the grapgh and I want it to be in the right side.

Comment: Here is the code:

hist(as.numeric(unlist((vels[counts]))),freq=F,col="gray",border="black",ylim=c(0,0.15),xlab=paste(names(vels)[counts]),main=paste("Weibull fitting",names(vels[counts])))

plot_weibull(K_value,A_value)

grid.table(round(values,3),cex=0.75,show.rownames=T,show.colnames=T,show.hlines=T)

Comment: put those details in the question, and include the variables `vels`, `counts`, `K_value` and `A_value` for instance using `dput(counts)` (unless it's too big, then be creative). Also include whatever packages you are using. In order to get help here you need to provide a reproducible example, so please edit your question

Comment: I'm guessing that `grid.table` is from `gridExtra`. It relies on grid graphics, so perhaps the problem is that `plot_weibull` uses base graphics. See `gridBase` to mix the two in the same device.

Comment: or use the `histogram` function from the `lattice` package (instead of `hist` from base R), which will use grid graphics.

Comment: what you've got here is better, but still not reproducible: http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hist` function is base graphics and the `grid.table` function is grid graphics.  The 2 graphics systems do not play nicely together without extra effort (as you have noticed).

The easiest fix is to use the `addtable2plot` function from the `plotrix` package rather than `grid.table`.  It may not look the same but it would be simple.

Another option is to use a grid graphics function to create the histogram, such as something from the `lattice` or `ggplot2` packages (both can do histograms), then create a specific viewport using grid graphics functions and use `grid.table` to put the table into that viewport.

Last, if you really want to mix them then see the `gridBase` package for ways to mix grid and base graphics.